# Uncertain how to set up the Neumann boundary conditions for Heat Equation Implicit FDM

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, boundary-value-problem, finite-differences

To smooth stock price data, I am currently looking to apply the heat equation
$$
u_\tau - \kappa u_{xx}=0
$$
with Neumann boundary conditions
$$
\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}(x_{min}+\Delta x, \tau)=0 \\
\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}(x_{max}-\Delta x, \tau)=0
$$
where $\Delta x = \frac{x_{max}-x_{min}}{N}$ and $N$ is the number of prices that are available for the stock in question.

Using central difference approximation
$$
\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}(x_{min} + \Delta x, \tau_{k+1}) = 
\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}(x_2 + \Delta x, \tau_{k+1})
= \frac{u_{1,k+1} - 2u_{2, k+1} + u_{3, k+1}}{h^2} + O(h^2)
$$
and setting it equal to $0$ gives
$$
u_{1,k+1}-2u_{2,k+1}+u_{3,k+1} = 0 \rightarrow u_{1,k+1}=2u_{2,k+1}-u_{3,k+1}
$$

Letting $\hat{l}$, $\hat{d}$, and $\hat{u}$ be the vectors corresponding to the lower diagonal, diagonal, and upper diagonal entries of $N$-by-$N$ matrix
$$
A_{Impact} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1+2\rho & -\rho & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
-\rho & 1+2\rho & -\rho & 0 &0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & -\rho & 1+2\rho & -\rho & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & -\rho & 1+2\rho & -\rho & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & -\rho & 1+2\rho & -\rho \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\rho & 1+2\rho
\end{bmatrix}
$$
respectively where $\rho = \frac{\kappa\Delta\tau}{\Delta x^2}$. Also, let the difference equation for j=x be
$$
\hat{l}_{x,k+1}u_{1,k+1} + \hat{d}_{x,k+1}u_{2,k+1} + \hat{u}_{x,k+1}u_{3,k+1}=u_{x,k}
$$
we can substitute the $u_{1,k+1}$ found above into the difference equation for $j=2$ for the left boundary
$$
\begin{align*}
\hat{l}_{2,k+1}u_{1,k+1} + \hat{d}_{2,k+1}u_{2,k+1} + \hat{u}_{2,k+1}u_{3,k+1}=u_{2,k} \\
\hat{l}_{2,k+1}u_{1,k+1} + \hat{d}_{2,k+1}u_{2,k+1} + \hat{u}_{2,k+1}u_{3,k+1}=u_{2,k} \\
\hat{l}_{2,k+1}\left(2u_{2,k+1}-u_{3,k+1}\right) + \hat{d}_{2,k+1}u_{2,k+1} + \hat{u}_{2,k+1}u_{3,k+1}=u_{2,k}\\
\left(\hat{d}_{2,k+1}-2\hat{l}_{2,k+1}\right)u_{2,k+1} + \left(\hat{u}_{2,k+1}+\hat{l}_{2,k+1}\right)u_{3,k+1}=u_{2,k}
\end{align*}
$$

Through similar methodology, we can also find the right boundary from central difference approximation giving 
$$
u_{N+1,k+1} = 2u_{N,k+1} - u_{N-1,k+1}
$$
and substituting into the difference equation for $j=N$
$$
\left(\hat{l}_{N,k+1}-\hat{u}_{N,k+1}\right)u_{N-1,k+1} + \left(\hat{d}_{N,k+1}+2\hat{u}_{N,k+1}\right)u_{N,k+1}=u_{N,k}
$$
This leaves me to conclude that the Neumann boundary conditions require
$$
\begin{align*}
\hat{d}_{0} = \hat{d}_{2,k+1}-2\hat{l}_{2,k+1} = (1+2\rho)-2(-\rho) = 1+4\rho \\
\hat{u}_{0} = \hat{u}_{2,k+1}+\hat{l}_{2,k+1} = (-\rho)+(-\rho) = -2\rho \\
\hat{d}_{N} = \hat{d}_{N,k+1}+2\hat{u}_{N,k+1} = (1+2\rho)+2(-\rho) = 1 \\
\hat{l}_{N-1} = \hat{l}_{N,k+1}-\hat{u}_{N,k+1} = (-\rho)-(-\rho) = 0
\end{align*}
$$
However, setting my diagonals with these values this leads the left ends of my smoothed curves to badly diverge negative, but I only think the right end doesn't diverge because it is really equal to the Dirichlet condition.
[image]

The code I am using is in [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/iCjCsLA1).

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: I apologize, I guess I mean to ask what it is I'm missing which is causing this drop-off on the extremes? I have the curves generated by Dirichlet conditions and they do not diverge like this and it's my first time attempting to implement Neumann @AEngineer

Comment: What's the definition of the N by N matrix? What are the Neumann boundary conditions?

Comment: @16278263789 I've edited the post to try and answer your questions. I apologize for the initially missing information.

Comment: No problem, no need to apologize, it's all good! Thanks!

Comment: Neumann boundary conditions would be $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\left(x_{min}+\Delta x,\tau\right)=\alpha$, a constant. Because $u_{\tau}=\kappa u_{xx}=0$ for your boundary conditions, you instead have $u\left(x_{min}+\Delta x,\tau\right)=\alpha$, a constant, so this is actually Dirichlet boundary conditions. How can you have an $N\times N$ matrix when you have either $N-1$ interior points between $x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$ or $N+1$ points if you count both endpoints as variables?

Comment: @user5713492 I'm confused, wouldn't having $\frac{du}{dx}(x_{min}+\Delta x, \tau)=\alpha$ lead to the second derivative being 0 since it's deriving a constant? With respect to the second part of your comment, I suppose I should make it $\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}(x_{min}, \tau)=\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}(x_{max}, \tau)=0$ then?

Comment: No, constancy in time at a given point in space doesn't mean constant in space. Given Neumann boundary conditions as in my last comment, then you could use a Taylor polynomial expanded about $x=x_0$:
$$\begin{array}{ll}u_0&=u_0\\
u_1&=u_0+\Delta x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac12(\Delta x)^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac16(\Delta x)^3\frac{\partial^3u}{\partial x^3}+O\left((\Delta x)^4\right)\\
u_2&=u_0+2\Delta x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+2(\Delta x)^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac43(\Delta x)^3\frac{\partial^3u}{\partial x^3}+O\left((\Delta x)^4\right)\end{array}$$

Comment: ... Then
$$8u_1-u_2-7u_0=6\Delta x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+2(\Delta x)^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+O\left((\Delta x)^4\right)$$
Where all derivatives are to be evaluated at $x=x_0$. Using the Neumann boundary condition, $\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right|_{x=x_0}=\alpha$ we solve for
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{8u_1-u_2-7u_0-6\alpha\Delta x}{2(\Delta x)^2}+O\left((\Delta x)^2\right)$$
This should get you the first row of your $(N+1)\times(N+1)$ matrix.

Comment: @user5713492 Thank you for the responses. I see what you mean about the constancy in time vs constancy in space and I suppose I can use $\frac{du}{dx}|_{x=x_0}=0$ instead of what I was thinking previously; however, I'm at a loss on the creation of this matrix. From my limited experience, I should be generating a diagonal matrix $A$ in order to proceed with my implied FDM. Beyond that, I don't really know how I'd proceed with the formulae you mention above if I don't know $u_0$, $u_1$, or $u_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems seem to be twofold. First, you need to understand how to derive the difference equations. I am going to let $x_0=x_{min}$, $x_j=x_0+j\Delta x$, $x_N=x_{max}$, $u_j=u(x_j,t)$, and $v_j=u(x_j,t+\Delta t)$. Expanding a Taylor polynomial about $x=x_0$,
$$\begin{array}{ll}u_0&=u_0\\
u_1&=u_0+\Delta x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac12(\Delta x)^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac16(\Delta x)^3\frac{\partial^3u}{\partial x^3}+O\left((\Delta x)^4\right)\\
u_2&=u_0+2\Delta x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+2(\Delta x)^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac43(\Delta x)^3\frac{\partial^3u}{\partial x^3}+O\left((\Delta x)^4\right)\end{array}$$
Where all the derivatives are to be evaluated at $x=x_0$. By the now clarified left boundary condition, $\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right|_{x=x_0}=0$ and so
$$8u_1-u_2-7u_0=2(\Delta x)^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+O\left((\Delta x)^4\right)$$
So we get
$$\frac{8u_1-u_2-7u_0}{2(\Delta x)^2}=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+O\left((\Delta x)^2\right)=\frac1{\kappa}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{v_0-u_0}{\kappa\Delta t}$$
Using the forward Euler method. Rewrite as
$$v_0=\left(1-\frac72\rho\right)u_0+4\rho u_1-\frac12\rho u_2$$
Where $\rho=\frac{\kappa\Delta t}{(\Delta x)^2}$. So the first row of our matrix reads $A_{00}=1-\frac72\rho$, $A_{01}=4\rho$, $A_{02}=-\frac12\rho$, and $A_{0j}=0$ for $2\le j\le N$.

For interior points, expanding in a Taylor series about $x=x_j$,
$$\begin{array}{ll}u_{j-1}&=u_j-\Delta x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac12(\Delta x)^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}-\frac16(\Delta x)^3\frac{\partial^3u}{\partial x^3}+O\left((\Delta x)^4\right)\\
u_j&=u_j\\
u_{j+1}&=u_j+\Delta x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac12(\Delta x)^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac16(\Delta x)^3\frac{\partial^3u}{\partial x^3}+O\left((\Delta x)^4\right)\end{array}$$
Where all derivatives are to be evaluated at $x=x_j$. Then
$$u_{j-1}+u_{j+1}-2u_j=(\Delta x)^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+O\left((\Delta x)^4\right)$$
So that
$$\frac{u_{j-1}+u_{j+1}-2u_j}{(\Delta x)^2}=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+O\left((\Delta x)^2\right)=\frac1{\kappa}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{v_j-u_j}{\kappa\Delta t}$$
Using the forward Euler method. Rewriting:
$$v_j=\rho u_{j-1}+\left(1-2\rho\right)u_j+\rho u_{j+1}$$
That means that for $1\le i\le N-1$, row $j$ reads $A_{j,j-1}=\rho$, $A_{jj}=1-2\rho$, $A_{j,j+1}=\rho$, and $A_{jk}=0$ for $k\notin\{j-1,j,j+1\}$.

**EDIT**: Another point which could be made here is that
$$u_{j+1}-u_{j-1}=2\Delta x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+O\left((\Delta x)^3\right)$$
So
$$\frac{u_{j+1}-u_{j-1}}{2\Delta x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+O\left((\Delta x)^2\right)$$
Which implies that fixing the first derivative at an interior point costs a degree of freedom in that its neighbor points are tied together: if we know the value of one, the other is given by the above equation.

Expanding in a Taylor polynomial about $x=x_N$,
$$\begin{array}{ll}u_{N-2}&=u_N-2\Delta x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+2(\Delta x)^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}-\frac43(\Delta x)^3\frac{\partial^3u}{\partial x^3}+O\left((\Delta x)^4\right)\\
u_{N-1}&=u_N-\Delta x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac12(\Delta x)^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}-\frac16(\Delta x)^3\frac{\partial^3u}{\partial x^3}+O\left((\Delta x)^4\right)\\
u_N&=u_N\end{array}$$
Hopefully we have also the right boundary condition that $\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right|_{x=x_N}=0$ so that
$$8u_{N-1}-u_{N-2}-7u_N=2(\Delta x)^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+O\left((\Delta x)^4\right)$$
So now
$$\frac{8u_{N-1}-u_{N-2}-7u_N}{2(\Delta x)^2}=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+O\left((\Delta x)^2\right)=\frac1{\kappa}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{v_N-u_N}{\kappa\Delta t}$$
Using the forward Euler method. Rewrite as:
$$v_N=-\frac12\rho u_{N-2}+4\rho u_{N-1}+\left(1-\frac72\rho\right)u_N$$
So the last row of the matrix is $A_{N,N-2}=-\frac12\rho$, $A_{N,N-1}=4\rho$, $A_{NN}=1-\frac72\rho$, and $A_{Nj}=0$ for $0\le j\le N-3$.

So that's how we can construct the $A$ matrix using the differential equation and Neumann boundary conditions. At each time step, we simply multiply the old $\vec u$ vector by the $A$ matrix to get the updated $\vec v$ vector:
$$\vec v=A\vec u$$
As for the second problem, read [the Wikipedia page on von Neumann stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis) where lo and behold exactly your heat equation is used as an example. The conclusion of that example is that the forward Euler method won't work in this case unless $\rho\le\frac12$. Try it out for yourself: if $\rho$ is a little smaller than $\frac12$, then everything proceeds normally but if $\rho$ is just a little bigger than $\frac12$, then everything goes blooey.

**EDIT**: With the following heat.txt

```
0     187.179993
1     183.919998
2     185.399994
3     187.970001
4     190.580002
5     190.350006
6     187.880005
7     191.029999
8     191.330002
9     190.910004
10    191.449997
11    190.399994
12    191.880005
13    191.440002
14    191.610001
15    193.000000
16    194.820007
17    194.210007
18    190.979996
19    189.910004
20    190.289993
21    201.500000
22    207.389999
23    207.990005
24    209.070007
25    207.110001
26    207.250000
27    208.880005
28    207.529999
29    208.869995
```

The Matlab code heat.m
**EDIT**: Modified to take advantage of the almost tridiagonal nature of the system. Seeing what happened when I made little mistakes in my modification, I think that's what was happening in your python code. Von Neumann stability is not a problem for the backward Euler method like it is for the forward method. In fact, due to the different nature of the boundary difference equations this implementation of the forward Euler method is unstable even before $\rho=0.4$.

```
% heat.m

clear all;
close all;
%backward = false;
backward = true;
raw = importdata('heat.txt');
u = raw(:,2);
t = raw(:,1);
N = length(u)-1;
rho = 0.15625;
if backward,
    rho = -rho;
end
% Set up A matrix
lower = rho*ones(size(u)); % Lower diagonl
lower(1) = -1/2*rho; % A(1,2)
lower(N+1) = 4*rho; % A(N+1,N)
d = (1-2*rho)*ones(size(u)); % Principal diagonal
d(1) = 1-7/2*rho; % A(1,1)
d(N+1) = 1-7/2*rho; % A(N+1,N+1)
upper = rho*ones(size(u)); % Upper diagonal
upper(1) = 4*rho; % A(1,2)
upper(N+1) = -1/2*rho; % A(N+1,N-1);

plot(t,u)
title('Smoothing Exercise');
xlabel('t');
ylabel('u');
hold on;
for k = 1:20,
    if backward,
        u = backward_step(lower,d,upper,u);
    else
        u = forward_step(lower,d,upper,u);
    end
    plot(t,u);
end
```

Also needed backward_step.m

```
% backward_step.m

function x = backward_step(l,d,u,b);

% On entry l, d, and u represent an (N+1)X(N+1) almost tridiagonal matrix A
% l is the lower diagonal: l(i) = A(i,i-1) except l(1) = A(1,3)
% d is the principle diagonal: d(i) = A(i,i)
% u = the upper diagonal: u(i) = A(i,i+1) except u(N+1) = A(N+1,N-1)

% On exit, x is the solution to A*x=b

% Make necessary copies -- not necessary for Matlab, which passes by value
N = length(b)-1;
dD = d;
x = b;
temp_1 = u(1);
temp_N = l(N+1);

% Perform an upwards step of Gaussian elimination:
temp = l(1)/u(2);
dD(1) = dD(1)-temp*l(2);
u(1) = u(1)-temp*dD(2); % Why we had to save u(1)
x(1) = x(1)-temp*x(2);

% Perform a downwards step of Gaussian elimination:
temp = u(N+1)/l(N);
l(N+1) = l(N+1)-temp*dD(N); % Why we had to save l(N+1)
dD(N+1) = dD(N+1)-temp*u(N);
x(N+1) = x(N+1)-temp*x(N);

% The two off-tridiagonal entries are eliminated, so the matrix is now
% tridiagonal. Sweep down:

for i = 2:N+1,
    temp = l(i)/dD(i-1);
    dD(i) = dD(i)-temp*u(i-1);
    x(i) = x(i)-temp*x(i-1);
end

% Now to sweep up:

x(N+1) = x(N+1)/dD(N+1);
for i = N:-1:1,
    x(i) = (x(i)-u(i)*x(i+1))/dD(i);
end

% Restore the two saved elements:

u(1) = temp_1;
l(N+1) = temp_N;
```

Or if backward == false, forward_step.m

```
% forward_step.m

function x = forward_step(l,d,u,b);

% On entry l, d, and u represent an (N+1)X(N+1) almost tridiagonal matrix A
% l is the lower diagonal: l(i) = A(i,i-1) except l(1) = A(1,3)
% d is the principle diagonal: d(i) = A(i,i)
% u = the upper diagonal: u(i) = A(i,i+1) except u(N+1) = A(N+1,N-1)

% On exit, x = A*b

N = length(b)-1;
x = zeros(size(b)); % Make solution vector of the right shape

% First row is different
x(1) = d(1)*b(1)+u(1)*b(2)+l(1)*b(3);

% Middle rows
for i = 2:N,
    x(i) = l(i)*b(i-1)+d(i)*b(i)+u(i)*b(i+1);
end

% Last row is also different
x(N+1) = u(N+1)*b(N-1)+l(N+1)*b(N)+d(N+1)*b(N+1);
```

Produced the following smoothed output
[image: heat1.png]

Comment: thank you for the thorough write-up, it greatly helped me in understanding the derivation of difference equations. I was wondering if the A matrix developed for the forward Euler works for the implicit backward Euler. I would think not, but the difference equations look like they should work universally. Beyond this, in terms of application through $v=Au$, do I just assume I have $u_0$, $u_1$, and $u_2$ from the data I obtain in my csv and proceed from there? Setting the A terms as you have shown still results in wild divergence at my extremes.

Comment: I think that if you want to use backward Euler and so solve $B\vec v=\vec u$ then then $B=2I-A$: it's the same as the $A$ matrix except with negative $\rho$. You said that you were using the heat equation to smooth data so I assume you have $u(x,0)$ as the bumpy data $u_0$, $u_1$, $u_2$, ... $u_N$. What was your value of $\rho$? As explained in my last paragraph above you need $\rho\le\frac12$ or you will for sure get wild divergence. Take more smoothing steps with smaller values of $\rho$ if necessary. Do you have a simple example of initial data and $\rho$ that exhibits your problem?

Comment: I currently use the code here: https://pastebin.com/L1C6Rmcv. Using the code in that pastebin yields the following plot: https://imgur.com/a/6cTvSpA. I did check my rho and it is ~0.15625 so I don't think that'd be an issue. A subset of the data I use can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/dMTiBJ4Q, with each row as the closing price of a stock each day. I suppose that it could be used as $u(x,0)$, but it is the closing price each day so that doesn't seem intuitive.

Comment: I am pretty much illiterate in python but it seems that your general matrix element is appropriate for the backward Euler method while the Neumann boundary stuff is what I gave for forward Euler. Since your diagSolver function seems to be solving a tridiagonal system by the method of sweeps, you should change the signs of the rho terms in your Neumann stuff. The $A$ matrix is not tridiagonal but you could do two preliminary steps of Gaussian elimination to knock out $A(0,2)$ and $A(N,N-2)$ and then the method of sweeps would work. Smoothing was OK for me both forward and backward (see code).

Comment: Thank you for the help and sticking with me even on sillier questions! I tried making A a tri-diagonal matrix, but haven't had any luck on that yet. For now I just translated your MatLab code into Python so I at least have something I can visualize while I continue to try and make the tridiagonal matrix work out. Any advice on how I could compare the Neumann and Dirichlet results beyond just eyeballing it?

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. The Neumann results should eventually converge to a constant, the average temperature of the system. The Dirichlet results should converge to a straight line joining the (constant) data points at the system extremes. At least that's what would happen for the continuous case. To get the tridiagonal code working I suggest letting the $l$, $d$, and $u$ vectors all have indices running from $0$ to $N$. Then set all the elements of $l$ and $u$ to $-\rho$ and all the elements of $d$ to $1+2\rho$. Then set $d(0)=A_{00}$, $u(0)=A_{01}$ and $l(0)=A_{02}$. Running out of space...

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but I heard the Neumann condition can be extended beyond just the first slope, like being used for the slope from the 1st point to the 10th point. I tried to implement something like this in the same way you showed above, except using $u_{10}$ and $u_{n-10}$ instead of $u_2$ and $u_{N-2}$ respectively, but that causes my boundaries to blow up. Have you heard of this before? Thanks again for the help on all of this!

Comment: Not a problem as I had been meaning to implement the method of sweeps for this problem anyhow (see changes). Putting boundary conditions on interior points doesn't make all that much sense to me, but it is easy to implement on the interior points: let $u_{11}-u_9=0$ replace your old $u_{10}$ equation and that will make $u_{10}^{\prime}=0$ but if you wanted to get rid of the old boundary condition on $u_0$ the actual differential equation translates to $$u_0^{\prime\prime}=\frac{2u_0-5u_1+4u_2-u_3}{\left(\Delta x\right)^2}+O\left(\left(\Delta x\right)^2\right)=0$$

Comment: Thanks for the response and clarification of the sweeps. If I recall correctly, it wasn't so much setting the interior points as it was setting the condition such that the slopes from $u_0$ to $u_{10}$ and $u_{N-10}$ to $u_N$ were fixed, which is why I tried doing the same boundaries as previous, except with $u_{10}$ and $u_{N-10}$. Not really sure how $u_{11} - u_9$ translates to that differential equation $u_0''$ though.

Comment: Mmmm, yeah, that should have been $$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{2u_0-5u_1+4u_2-u_3}{(\Delta x)^2}+O\left((\Delta x)^2\right)=\frac1{\kappa}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{v_0-u_0}{\kappa\Delta t}$$

Comment: I assumed that part, but how did you go from $u_{11}$ and $u_9$ to $u_0, u_1,u_2, \text{ and } u_3$

Comment: Every boundary condition that you impose wipes out a degree of freedom that allowed free diffusion to happen. See today's edit. Thus I assumed that when fixing the derivative at some interior point you wanted to let the endpoint float so it could follow the diffusion equation just like all the other points, which must be modified as a difference equation because endpoints only have neighbors on one side. But if you start constraining the derivative at a lot of points you have to forget about diffusion for the same number of points so you are changing the nature of the problem.

Comment: I see. Thank you for all the insight. One last thing and I think I'll be good. I tried to implement the sweeps as you appear to have implemented them; however, I get some odd plots. Mainly, as the number of iterations I use increases, the curve generated gets closer and closer to the output of Dirichlet boundary conditions. This can be seen here: https://imgur.com/a/NGWQ87g. The code I wrote based off your examples is here: https://pastebin.com/mwdwxBwM. I apologize it's in Python, I don't have MatLab.

Comment: You are modeling the heat equation and if you had any kind of wierd temperature distribution over the length of a bar and the ends were perfectly insulated, eventually the whole bar would arrive at the average temperature. The time you are waiting for the temperature to even out is proportional to $\rho$ times the number of time steps taken.

Comment: On lines 4:6 you define `l`, `d`, and `u` as arrays with `N` elements indexed from $0$ to $N-1$  
$$$$`l = np.zeros((n,1))`
$$$$`d = np.zeros((n,1))`
$$$$`u = np.zeros((n,1))`
$$$$So I think line 44 goes one step too far  
$$$$`for i in range(1,N):`
$$$$As does line 52  
$$$$`for i1 in range(N-2,-1,-1):`